# How to make colored boxes in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to make colored boxes using Sphinx for Python.

For example, this website has a lot of gray div or boxes (not the Note ones): http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

I'm wondering how they manage to create thoses boxes since this website is also created using sphinx.

One thing I found, is that Sphinx has built in colored boxes as shown here: http://openalea.gforge.inria.fr/doc/openalea/doc/_build/html/source/sphinx/rest_syntax.html#colored-boxes-note-seealso-todo-and-warnings. Those boxes would work perfectly for me if they didn't have the words "Note:", "SeeAlso" or "Warning" in the beginning.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already find the "Show source" button on the page you are referencing?

Comment: You provided an example: http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html On this page, there is a "Show source"-button that shows you the sources of the same page... in the source you can see that the gray box is a source-code-block

Answer (score 11):

Things like notes, warnings, and such are called [admonitions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#admonitions).  Unfortunately, you can't create ones that don't have a title, as it's required by reStructuredText.

The other boxes on that page are from [code blocks](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#showing-code-examples).  Code blocks are run through the [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) color syntax highlighter.

There are a couple of other ways to get what you want.  You could [embed raw HTML](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through), but that's frowned upon.  The other choice might be to [write an extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html) to create a directive that gives you the functionality you need.